Is it possible for a species to be completly non-sexually dimorphic?
In my fantasy setting, I have dragons (Because dragons are cool) and I thought that there would be some interesting storytelling potential if the dragons were completely non-sexually dimorphic (Including everything down to genitalia, meaning that any two individuals could reproduce with each other.). Would this be possible, and how would this evolve naturally?

if any two individuals could reproduce, that is a hermaphrodite. Yes that is a thing for some species.

VTC - this question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/170299/could-reptiles-be-simultaneous-hermaphrodites - if we consider Dragons to be Reptiles (which traditionally they are) - already answers the question

Huh, I didn't know there was a word for this. Good to know.

Yep, slugs, snails, some fish etc.. It's not usual in vertebrates - but if that's what you want in your world, then why not.

@nadichamp No worries, glad we could help

You might also consider sequential hermaphroditism. Some fish start as male, then as they get older and bigger turn female.

simultaneous hermaphroditism as you suggest tends to only stick around with a species that is isolated and have trouble finding potential mates.  In species that are mobile enough for an individual to easily find numerous potential mates it tends to go away since at this point specializing in a mating strategy is better then being mediocre at both and thus being forced to act like a sub-par female always.  It wouldn't make sense for a mobile flying species to be hermaphrodites.  Admittedly few will know enough about evolution to question that fact if you ignore it.

actually come to think of it an all female parthenogenetic dragon race may make more sense.  Basically all dragons are female and will give birth to clones of themselves.  Parthenogenesis only requires one mutation to become common in a wild species.  Admittedly Parthenogenetic species ultimately die out due to their lack of adaptability, but humans may be protecting them from most of those risks.  Only real problem is that this means you can't breed better dragons, dragons wouldn't become more domesticated or easier to handle no matter how long they interacted with humans.
